# Magento2.4.4 Place order using stripe payment method through REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, stripe

From stripe sdk I am able to create payment id successfully but when call api to create order in magento2 then getting authentication error.

I am  calling below API
http://localhost/xxx/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

with below body

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "stripe_payments",
        "additional_data": {
                   "cc_stripejs_token": "pm_1LqgYeSIs8FpUNNkeMFrz05K"
        }
    },
  "billing_address": {
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "region": "New York",
    "region_id": 43,
    "region_code": "NY",
    "country_id": "US",
    "street": [
      "123 Oak Ave"
    ],
    "postcode": "10577",
    "city": "Purchase",
    "telephone": "512-555-1111",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }
}
```

and getting below error

Authentication Required: pi_3LqfaVSIs8FpUNNk1KdMRl8U_secret_NsK4Xtg0SEdlO4asn2ipnQAhh

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error via grapqhl call. have you got any solution for this issue? then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Are you a logged-in user? You must be logged in to use the `carts/mine/payment-information` endpoint (https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/cartsminepayment-information#operation/PostV1CartsMinePaymentinformation).

If you are a guest user, you should use `guest-carts/{cartId}/payment-information` as described here https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/guest-cartscartIdpayment-information#operation/PostV1GuestcartsCartIdPaymentinformation